# Challenging Python list intersection

Tags: python, list, math, set, intersection

I have two lists as follows:

```
list_1 = [ [4,9], [10,14], [18,20], [21,23]]
list_2 = [ [3,5], [6,9], [10,11], [12,13], [14,16], [17,23] ]
```

And I need to find the intersection of these two using these rules:

1. All numbers in the list are sorted.
2. There are no 0 or negative numbers in any list.
3. Only select those intersections where the range difference is >= 2

So using above rules, intersection result should be:

```
[ [6,9], [18,20],[21,23] ]
```

I represented this problem in this image by distributing numbers on a line:

[image]

UPDATE: posted my own answer below

Comment: Please show us the code you have already written to solve the problem!

Comment: I don't understand the rules. Why are `[14, 16]`, `[18, 20]`, and `[20, 23]` supposed to be in the result? There is no intersection at all there.

Comment: Have you looked into `itertools.permutations` / `itertools.combinations` as a way to generate all possible combinations and then filter using your rules?

Comment: Concerning rule 3: The "range difference" – difference between what exactly?

Comment: I feel like if you take the time to more explicitly define your "range difference" criterion, you may answer your own question...

Comment: @KlausD. added the code

Comment: @StuartBuckingham I corrected the description.

Comment: @KlausD. rule 3 says the intersection result range element difference should be >= 2

Comment: @mkrieger1 I updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution using heuristic approach, but I am sure it's not pretty :(

```
def intersect_windows(list_1, list_2):
  if not list_1 or not list_2:
    return []

  list_1 = [range(x[0], x[1]) for x in list_1]
  list_2 = [range(x[0], x[1]) for x in list_2]

  result = []

  for s1 in list_1:
    for s2 in list_2:
      intr = [max(s1[0], s2[0]), min(s1[-1], s2[-1])+1]
      if (intr[1] - intr[0]) >= 2:
        result.append(intr)

  return result

##Usage

list_1 = [ [4,9], [10,14], [18,20], [21,23]]
list_2 = [ [3,5], [6,9], [10,11], [12,13], [14,16], [17,23] ]
intersect_windows(list_1, list_2)
```

> > `[[6, 9], [18, 20], [21, 23]]`

Answer (score -3):

Following your definitions, and the intersection in a broad sense what I got is:

```
list_1 = [ [4,9], [10,14], [18,20], [21,23]]
list_2 = [ [3,5], [6,9], [10,11], [12,13], [14,16], [17,23] ]
list_range1 = [item for sublist in [range(a, b+1) for a,b in list_1] for item in sublist]
list_range2 = [item for sublist in [range(a, b+1) for a,b in list_2] for item in sublist]
c = list(set(list_range1) & set(list_range2))
c.sort()
ans1 = [a for a in list_1 if (a[0] in c and a[1] in c)] + [a for a in list_2 if (a[0] in c and a[1] in c)]
ans2 = [a for a in ans1 if not a[0] == a[1]-1 ]
```

If correct (not sure as not sure I got the question) the answer to your example should contain as well

```
[[4, 9], [10, 14]]
```

As in the list2 [3,5], [6,9] is not distinguishable from [3,9]. 
If you want to distinguish them, you should do -1 for each second term of each list, and then add a +1.

Comment: thank for the snippet. But [4,9] cannot be in the intersection, as in list_2, you can see there is gap between 5 to 6